# props value is populating only after second click of button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

in parent functional component:

```
let [response, setresponse] = useState("undefined");

samplefunction = () => {
    setresponse("completed click");
}
```

in the child component:

```
<Button onClick={
    ()=> {
             props.samplefunction();
             console.log(props.response);
         }
}>Sample button</Button>
```

The problem is the `props.response` is giving value = **completed click** only after two clicks of the button.
upon single click, it is displaying the value = **undefined** which is deafult value from parent component

Comment: The operation to set the state is asynchronous, so it won't be available until after the click handler finishes.  The solution in this case is simply that you don't *need* to log the value to the console where you are attempting to do so.  The state is still being updated and the component re-rendered.

Comment: Actually I need to render something conditionally based on the props value. 
Is there any alternative where I could perform the same immediately after OnClick ?

Comment: The conditional rendering will still work.  Try building your conditional rendering instead of just logging to the console.  When the state is updated that triggers a re-render of the component, in which the new state will be available to the rendering logic.

Comment: Thanks. I went for conditional rendering outside the OnClick method and it worked. thanks for the inputs @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the state on the first click. A state change triggers a rerender of your component, that takes time and wont happen "inline".
So

```
props.samplefunction();
console.log(props.response);
```

to the time you log the state its still the old state, then components get rerendered and the new state is accessible.
Just render the state with {{ props.response }} or log it in the component code, not the click handler or JSX and you will see that you are doing it just right.